# Spring-Data-JPA method save(Iterable<S>) is not applicable for the arguments (Book)

Tags: spring, jpa

I am using spring-data-jpa 1.3.2.RELEASE. I was trying to save a Book object in my service. I am getting the following error: The method save(Iterable) in the type JpaRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Book). My method looks like this.

```
@Autowired 
private BookRepository bookRepository;

public Book save(Book book){
 return bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

Updated

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
   public Book save(Book book);
}
```

Comment: show BookRepository interface, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You do not need to define a save method. It is inherited from JPARepository.

Answer (score 0):

Dont write specifically save method, Jpa Repo itself given it.